# Why componentWillReceiveProps is triggered only if component initially had props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

When writing tests, I've noticed inexplicable behavior of `componentWillReceiveProps`.

This hook seems to be triggered only if component was initially mounted with props.

It looks like when I do `component.setProps()` on a "empty" component, `componentWillReceiveProps` is either not fired, or has no effect.

```
// TEST fails:
test('tracking URL preview input field has URL by default', () => {
    let component = mount(<Tracking />);

    expect(component.find('input').props().value.length).toBe(0);

    /* triggers componentWillReceiveProps and thus renderTrackingUrlPreview, 
       which changes input's props: */
    component.setProps(); 

    expect(component.find('input').props().value.length).toBeGreaterThan(0); // false, input is still empty
});

// TEST passes:
test('tracking URL preview input field has URL by default', () => {
    let component = mount(<Tracking tokenArr={urlTokens} />);

    expect(component.find('input').props().value.length).toBe(0);

    /* triggers componentWillReceiveProps and thus renderTrackingUrlPreview, 
       which changes input's props: */
    component.setProps(); 

    expect(component.find('input').props().value.length).toBeGreaterThan(0); // true, input has value
});
```

**Why the first test fails?**

Component's `constructor` and `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        tokenArr:    [],
        trackingUrl: ''
    };
    this.renderTrackingUrlPreview = this.renderTrackingUrlPreview.bind(this);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
        tokenArr: nextProps.tokenArr, 
        trackingUrl: this.renderTrackingUrlPreview(nextProps.tokenArr) // returns string (which is never empty)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - it has nothing to do with `componentWillReceiveProps`, it works as expected.

First test failed because `renderTrackingUrlPreview` was not prepared for empty `tokenArr` and in effect returned undefined error which prevented further execution. I somehow missed that in the midst of printed stack trace.